# module.export Unit Test Issue in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have two functions on a page and they contain a lot of jQuery. Code is below

```
 module.exports = function(property) {
    var data = decodeEntities(property)
}

function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
     let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
     textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
     return textArea.value;
}
```

I need to write test cases for decodeEntities function. But i have not premission to change `module.exports = function(property)` this code, because its call from handlebars template.

Now how may I test decodeEntities function's unit test without export it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) module to get the `decodeEntities` function which is not exported. E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(property) {
  var data = decodeEntities(property);
};

function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
  let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
  return textArea.value;
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const mod = rewire('./');

describe('60349818', () => {
  describe('#decodeEntities', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      const mElement = { innerHTML: '', value: 'some value' };
      const mCreateElement = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mElement);
      mod.__set__('document', {
        createElement: mCreateElement,
      });
      const decodeEntities = mod.__get__('decodeEntities');
      const actual = decodeEntities('encodedString');
      expect(actual).toEqual('some value');
      expect(mCreateElement).toBeCalledWith('textarea');
    });
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60349818/index.test.js
  60349818
    #decodeEntities
      ✓ should pass (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.334s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60349818